# How to implement google maps search by address in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

How to implement google maps search by address in Android?

Comment: Do you want to get location using address?

Comment: yes, I want to get location by address. But before that it should perform Google Maps search.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For that you need to create one map overlay class in map activity.

### Example

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.pink);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-32, null);         
        return true;
    }
}
```

Where please change `R.drawable.pink` . Put your any drawable.

Now please write below code in your search `onClick` event..

### Example

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(txtsearch.getText().toString(),5);

if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    p = new GeoPoint( (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

    controller.animateTo(p);
    controller.setZoom(12);

    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = map.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

    map.invalidate();
    txtsearch.setText("");
}
else {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(GoogleMap.this);
    adb.setTitle("Google Map");
    adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
    adb.setPositiveButton("Close",null);
    adb.show();
}
```

Where **txtsearch** is a `EditText` and **controller** is a map controller ..

Comment: GeoCoder is a class which can returns the address on basis of latitude and longitude and vice versa.

Comment: thanks a lot.... u mean to say,if i supply only name then geocoder will find lontitude and latitude for that particular address..

Comment: http://marakana.com/s/tutorial_android_location_service_example,311/index.html . Check this link

Comment: can u share any example in which i can search a city via google maps.

Comment: Can't we use itemized Overlay instead of mapoverlay?

Comment: @ChiragRaval com.google.android.maps.Overlay is not resolved. Have you used android-google-maps-api11.jar or something else?