# Enable user to search for a location in GMaps in android apps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android development, I have enable gmap view in my application, now I want to enable user to search for a location in GMaps, I have searched alot but can not find, way, Please suggest me some Idea or web links.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MapOverlay class in your activity. [How to implement google maps search by address in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375654/how-to-implement-google-maps-search-by-address-in-android) will help you do that. (Check the first answer)