# Have android app open up google maps with search query

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maps

So I am trying to make an app and my next step is that when the user clicks a specific button it will open up google maps with a pre defined search query. THis is my first app. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
    String uri = String.format("geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude); // for example pass geo:75.333000,30.003030 to search for latitude = 75.333000 and longitude = 30.003030 as your default search query
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how exactly would I link this to a button?

Comment: Put this code inside your onClick listener.

Comment: Updated code in the answer. :)

Comment: gotcha! and my button is named button2 so I must include that correct?

Comment: and is it possible to pull the text which is stored in a textView and have that be the google maps query rather than a latitude and a longitude?

Comment: Yeah, Just change mButton in my code to button2 (assuming that you are talking about its name in the java file)

Comment: What will be the content in your textView ? Latitudes or the name of the street ?

Comment: It's just a keyword. Say "Chinese food"

Comment: Have a look at the code given here and I hope it would help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375654/how-to-implement-google-maps-search-by-address-in-android

Comment: And please do upvote the answers that you find helpful. Cheers. Thanks. :)

Comment: it won't let me. It says I need 15 reputation

Comment: do you think it will be easier to jsut implement a google search rather than maps?

Comment: Google search would be a lot easier I believe.