# how to get location from Edit view and then show that in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, search

I am working with google maps. I want the user to enter location as a string in the edittext and to animate the map towards that location. Also while user enters the string i also want to provide hints about the location. What should i do?

Comment: location means area name or lat-lon information ?

Answer (score 1):

**Animation**

You have to set a default point and then when you got the new GeoPoint you should send it to the Map controller and call animateTo

```
mapController.animateTo(point)
```

** Insert location **

You can have look on that link: [How to implement google maps search by address in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375654/how-to-implement-google-maps-search-by-address-in-android)

Comment: thanks!!! I also want to take string/location as input from user.. and while the user is entering the location in edittext i want to display the hints or matched locations so that user can choose from that as well ??? Plz help

Comment: I am not sure that Google has this method to give you hints, you can get address from a point and then create a kind of "helper"

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Google's Autocomplete widget if it suits your app. If not then, you need to use a content provider for fetching places from [Google places autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically), which can be then shown in the form of a dialog. Check out the example [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/)