# Google Maps Search by Address in Android

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

For Implementing Google Maps Search by Address

i followed the below Answer in stackoverflow

[How to implement google maps search by address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5375840/1904932)

i Tried almost 2 days and searched for solutions not found.

Here i am adding My code

activity_search_map.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#3b3b3b">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
         android:background="#2a2a2a"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText1"
             android:layout_width="450dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:ems="10" >

             <requestFocus />
         </EditText>

  <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btnmapsites"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Go" 
         android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"/>  

  </LinearLayout>



<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0Hy-jVRgYeXOLNcLWl8N7bFl4spAl7s4SX4cYSg"
/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

SearchMapActivity.java  (Main Activity class)

```
package com.example.searchmap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SearchMapActivity extends Activity {

    Geocoder geoCoder;
    EditText editText;
    GeoPoint p;
    MapController controller;
    MapView mapView;
    Button btngo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_map);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        btngo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmapsites);

          btngo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                             

            public void onClick(View arg0) {


        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(editText.getText().toString(),1);
            if(addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                 p = new GeoPoint( (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                                  (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                   controller.animateTo(p);
                   controller.setZoom(12);

                   MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                 List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays(); 
                         listOfOverlays.clear();
                 listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                   mapView.invalidate();
                   editText.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchMapActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                    adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
                    adb.setPositiveButton("Close",null);
                    adb.show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
            });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_search_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

MapOverlay.java

```
package com.example.searchmap;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
     GeoPoint p = null;
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-32, null);         
        return true;
    }

    private Resources getResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

LogCat  - the error i got in my LogCat - please go through this

```
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.searchmap/com.example.searchmap.SearchMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.example.searchmap.SearchMapActivity.onCreate(SearchMapActivity.java:38)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     ... 11 more
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.searchmap-2.apk]
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
12-14 19:46:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     ... 20 more
```

please help me

Comment: Your Main Activity class can NOT obtain your address because you are trying to get the address within 'public void onClick(View arg0) {..'. Now your trying causes the Sync collision. Try to get the address formular(ie."...List<Address> addresses;
        try {....") out of the main thread. To get the correct address, Please refer to [this good sample tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log message --

> "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.searchmap-2.apk]

Clues you in that you appear to be running on a device without Google Maps API on it.  If it is an emulator go to your AVD manager and create a new AVD with a target that has "Google APIs (Google Inc.) -- API Level X" where X is your target API.

If this is a real device, it looks like you have one without google maps support, try in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.searchmap-2.apk]

Here `data` means SD card. If the SD Card has been removed from the device, and if the app is stored on it, then opening the app crashes as above because the device is not able to find the APK. I can reproduce in HTC sensation version 2.3.4.