# How to search streets in Google Maps api2 for Android

Tags: android, search, maps, google-maps-api-2

In my app, I want to let the user search for street (as in google maps web), and then display a cuople or markers and the route to the searched street.

But, I dont found how to add the "Search Box" to the map. I see in this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375654/how-to-implement-google-maps-search-by-address-in-android) something that "could" work for me , but, the class `com.google.android.maps.Overlay` is not available :S

And I dont know how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

google maps api (both versions v1 and v2) are just for the map.

any search, route functionality have to implemented by your self (put a search box on the action bar, call up a service get you the date, etc, etc).

Comment: So I Will need to do the "cool" functionality in some thread, or something like that, correct? and then show it on the map or in the ActionBar