# How to set google maps to an address by user input

Tags: android, google-maps

I have implemented google maps in my application, but it takes latitude and longitude for its operation, i want the application to use the address given by the user, i have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375654/how-to-implement-google-maps-search-by-address-in-android/5375840#5375840) solution but i am not able to get it right. Any link or link of a complete tutorial will be of great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example given by Sajith4U is very near to be perfect however it is missing few things, 
 it is missing the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And very importantly

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Add these lines in your manifest and you are good to run the app. Just make sure that you are changing the package name in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

This links give you better answer. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/locating-user-input-address-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-with-geocoding-api/